# WPF access viewmodel from Converter

Tags: wpf, viewmodel, converters

I have a Label that translates a code inserted by the user to the description. For that I am using a Dictionary inside a converter.
This Dictionary is filled in every call to the Converter throw a Service. This is a really ugly thing, and I wanted to have this dictionary in my viewmodel but I have no ideia how to access it from the converter.

Any ideia?

Comment: Is it possible to see any sample code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your view, bind the dictionary as a resource (supplied by the ViewModel). Change the converter to an `IMultiValueConverter` and use a `<MultiBinding>` to bind it to both the value that you need to use for lookup, and to the dictionary that you're looking up in.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.imultivalueconverter.aspx for more information on converters taking multiple input values, and an example of using one with a `<MultiBinding>`.

Alternatively, as GazTheDestroyer proposed, put it in your ViewModel.

```
class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

   public MyViewModel()
   {
      // Call service to populate _dictionary here...
   }

   private Dictionary<string, string> _dictionary;
   private string _code;

   public string Code
   {
      get { return _code; }
      set
      {
         _code = value;
         Description = _dictionary[_code];
         if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Description"));
      }
   }

   public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

And instead of binding through a converter, bind to the Description property.

**UPDATE**

To answer your question about updating, you'll need to change the binding in your XAML slightly to change the UpdateSourceTrigger. The default for a Text property is to update when the control loses focus, this will change it to every time the value changes:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Code,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

Further reading is available at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.updatesourcetrigger.aspx

You may have to add some error validation here - every keystroke will alter the value of Description so you may want to include some logic in your ViewModel to only change the value when there is a value to use, or grey out a value that does not correspond to the (half-finished) code. These are usability things though, you can play around to find what is best for your application.

Comment: the thing is, when I implement that code, the label that is binded to the Description Property is not refresh when the user alter the Code. I imagine I would have to implement some event for this no?

Comment: Yes, you might have to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on the ViewModel and trigger it in your setter. I'll update the example. INotifyPropertyChanged is pretty important in MVVM stuff, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged.aspx is the link you want.

Comment: Ok, now it is working with just 1 drawback. The property is only refresh when I focus another control and not when I actually alter de Code textbox. Is there anyway I can solution this?

Comment: Updated answer to include this.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you are the man. It got perfect, with your code examples and documentation!

Comment: GazTheDestroyer deserves a +1 for the idea, I just put some examples on.

Answer (score 2):

If you put it in the viewmodel you won't need a converter.

Simply expose a `Code` property in your VM and bind the label to that. Then in the `Code` setter you use your dictionary to update your `Description` property.

Comment: In your solution when is the Code refreshed?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The Code is altered when the user alters it. Or are you saying that the same label is used for both the code and the description?

Comment: the thing is, when I implement that solution, the label that is binded to the Description Property is not refresh when the user alter the Code. I imagine I would have to implement some event for this no?

Comment: Your VM should implement INotifyPropertyChanged and all properties on your VM should fire PropertyChanged events. Without this WPF will not know your property has changed.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I've used your solution just marked the other one because the code posted was useful to understand the solution.

Comment: No probs. Pete fleshed it out for you nicely.